# Regular expression to match different versions of same word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression to match different versions of the same word.

for example:

If I have `jQuery,jquery,JQUERY,Jquery` -> they should all be matched and total match count should be 4.
I tried:

```
((jquery?)||(jQuery?)||(JQUERY?)||(Jquery))
```

but it gives me each word count individually.(i.e jquery:1, jQuery:1, JQUERY:1, JQuery:1)

I need **jquery:4**

My whole code:

```
var wordMatch = /((react?)|(angular?)|(javascript?)|(node?)|(mongo ?)|((jquery?)||(jQuery?)||(JQUERY?))|(backbone?))/gmi;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like to just count each case insensitive instance of a certain word? If so, you could just have `var count = mystring.match(/baseword/gi).length;` to get the number of times your base word is mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

First, case insensitive matching is what the `i` flag is for, and you're already using that. `/jquery/i` will catch both `jquery` and `jQuery`, so you don't need so many options in your regex.

Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do with the `?`s, but it seems wrong. `?` makes the preceding character or group optional, so `/jquery?/` matches both `jquery` and `jquer` - probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
/(string)/gi
```

This will return all matches of "string" in the same group, not caring about casing.